# How can i fork Binance Smart Chain and create my own blockchain

Tags: fork, blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I want to fork Binance smart chain so that i can have a whole new blockchain.

By this i mean it will have a new name, ticker, users will be able to develop on top of it just like BSC.

How do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have git installed type this in your terminal

```
Git clone https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc.git
```

and if you don't have git installed you can download the bsc file right off of GitHub [Here](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc) click code and then click download zip
warning most of it is written in Golang but if all your trying to do if change the name and ticker you should be able to do that fairly easily by looking around in the files for more info on it check their [GitHub](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc)

Comment: Will changing the name and ticker and running the resulting executable effectively start a new blockchain? Would there be any changes required in the network discovery functionality, like changing the port it runs on, etc.? What else do I need to fork to have a competing blockchain and tooling?

Comment: I would use the cosmos sdk that can help you with your questions scroll down and hit start tutorial https://v1.cosmos.network/sdk

Comment: Cosmos seems interesting. Thank You, I'll go through the tutorial. Any other suggestions for such a project?

Comment: not any other suggestions that I can think of as long as you know Golang and follow the cosmos tutorial you should be fine